# different visual style for xp theme compared to windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp, visual-styles

I have developed an application in visual studio 2010 (on a x86 win7 machine) and the GUI displays as designed when ran on a windows 7 machine. However, when on xp (using ANY theme) it loses all display functionality! Colours are wrong, buttons change etc and even changes font colours.

Is there anything I can do to keep the appearance no matter the OS?

Comment: You should include a screenshot of what you're seeing. i have applications developed on Windows 7 that appear fine on Windows XP. (Native Win32 and WinForms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked what theme the user has, if it isn't Windows 7 theme then change display.